# Chrome extension - How to return a promise value from executed script in callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

**Background.js:**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, 
{
    file: "exec_script.js"
}, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

**exec_script.js:**

```
var test = html2canvas(document.body, {
  allowTaint: false,
  letterRendering: true,
  logging: true
}).then(function (canvas) {
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
    var bImage = dataUrl.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
});
test
```

As far as I know, the last statement in exec_script.js have to be passed to the callback as the result parameter. But it returns empty object.

But if I make as following in exec_script.js:

```
var test = "good";
test
```

It returns a value of the variable to the callback.

Also the tab is not focused.

Comment: _"But it returns empty object"_ Are you sure `res` is a plain object? What value are you expecting to be passed to callback?

Comment: I want to see "bImage" value in the callback.

Comment: Have you tried to `return` `bImage` from `.then()` chained to `html2canvas` call, chaining `.then()` to `res` at callback?

Comment: Like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4nucrpa9/) ? Yes, I've tried. The problem is that the `chrome.tabs.executeScript` doesn't block the extension process until the code in the tab has finished.

Comment: `test` does not reference `bImage` value. `test` is a `Promise`, `.then()` is used to get `Promise` value.

Comment: Like this [https://jsfiddle.net/twmaqt2u/](https://jsfiddle.net/twmaqt2u/) ? It doesn't work too. Returns an empty array.

Comment: Have you tried chaining `.then()` to `test` http://jsfiddle.net/4nucrpa9/1 or `res` https://jsfiddle.net/4nucrpa9/2/?

Comment: The tab is not active. It sends nothing untill I select tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

The result returned by `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is produced by the main body of the executed script, in other words it is the standard behavior of synchronous JavaScript.

In your case the synchronous part creates `test` object, schedules a Promise but doesn't execute it yet ([a task/microtask is queued](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/)), puts the just initialized `test` object as the last statement so that it gets picked up by executeScript. Furthermore, since executeScript transfers only JSON-ifiable portion of objects, and `test` being a complex class object, an empty object is transferred. You can check it manually by inspecting `console.log(JSON.stringify(test))` in the console.

To transfer the results of asynchronous code use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging):

- background.js

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log(sender.tab, msg);
      // do something
  });
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "exec_script.js"});
  ```
- exec_script.js

  ```
  var test = html2canvas(document.body, {
    allowTaint: false,
    letterRendering: true,
    logging: true
  }).then(function(canvas) {
      var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
      var bImage = dataUrl.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({dataUrl: dataUrl});
  });
  ```

N.B. only JSON-ifiable portion of objects is transferred via messaging.